# What happened to this CPL filter?

Tags: filters, equipment-damage

What happened to these CPL filters?  Is it reversible?  Can they be cleaned or fixed?  The damage looks like it is inside the glass. I'm concerned it's fungus or something else.

My father bought them around 2014. I’m a beginner, and never used them.

[Here’s a clip of the filter](https://www.dropbox.com/s/fguonzb812z4mkt/Steinzeiser%20CPL%20Filters.mov?dl=0)

[image: screenshot 1]

[image: screenshot 2]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Polarizing filters are made up of several layers.  Since the problem looks like it's "inside" the glass, the layers are probably separating (delamination).

Trying to repair the filter would cost more than just replacing it.

Comment: Or one (or more) of the coatings has failed. It's common for CPL's to have 10+ coatings

Comment: @spikey_richie OP states that it looks like it's "inside" the glass.  Coatings are usually on the surface.